# Limits of $\frac{e\frac{1}{x}}{x(1-e^{\frac{1}{x}})}$ for $x\to0, \infty$

Tags: limits

What is the limit of the following expression ;

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{e\frac{1}{x}}{x\left[1-e^{\frac{1}{x}}\right]}$$

and

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{e\frac{1}{x}}{x\left[1-e^{\frac{1}{x}}\right]}$$

I have tried with looking at many documents. Could you give the answer or give some hints about how to find the following limits ?

Comment: Are you familiar with L'Hospital's rule? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $1-e^{\frac1x} \sim -\frac1x$ as $x\to \infty$. Then

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^{\frac1x}}{x(1-e^{\frac1x})} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^{\frac1x}}{x(-\frac1x))} = \lim_{x\to\infty}-e^{\frac1x} = -1$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: let $z=1/x$, you get
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{e^{1/x}}{x(1-e^{1/x})}=\lim_{z\to 0}
\frac{ze^{z}}{1-e^{z}}=\lim_{z\to 0}e^{z}\frac{z}{1-e^{z}}.$$
What is $\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{z}{1-e^{z}}$?

Comment: I know that it is silly to say, $e^z$ goes to zero but $\frac{z}{1-e^{z}}$ goes to zero also ? because I suppose it makes $\frac{0}{0}$.

Comment: Not really, $e^z\to 1$ as $z\to 0$. $\frac{e^z-1}{z}\to 1$ as $z\to 0$, hence $\frac{z}{1-e^z}\to -1$.